# Spotfire: Calculated Column to find if a different event in same column occurs within 1 hour

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

The calculated column I am trying to create is the far right column in the below table:

In words:
If a B event occurs in the specified City, does a C event occur within one hour of the B event, true or false.

I've tried a few different approaches with Over functions but just not having luck. I am struggling on how to reference a different event in the same column and then calculate a datetime difference between them..

[image: olu]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to take it in stages and define intermediate columns.
Try this, assuming C is the max label for the events.

You did not post data so I generated something that seemed similar.

([event]="B") and (Max([event]) OVER (Intersect([city],AllNext([date])))="C") and (
DateDiff("hh",[date],ValueforMax([event],[date]) OVER (Intersect([city],AllNext([date]))))<=1)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much! Do you know how I would make this work if C was not the max value? I am trying to learn here, trying to do what you provided would've taken me forever. Thanks! I want to get to this level haha

Comment: Also, with the solution you provided, it records a TRUE or FALSE for each row, is there a way to only report for the B events? maybe use a case when then end approach?

Comment: If C were not the max value, you can go into the column properties of the dataset, locate the [event] column, tab Sort Order and configure a custom sort order so that the new value is last in order. For removing the results should the event not be B, you cannot put a case around the original definition because it then would no longer look at C events. I would create a second calculated column like this  CASE [event] when 'B' then [originalflag] else NULL end. Where [originalflag] is the previous solution I posted